# Flutter iOS style UIKit dynamic view animations

Tags: flutter, dart

Recently I’ve noticed some cool bouncing effect when you scroll messages in iMessage chat.
I’ve found it’s possible to do using objective-c and UIKit dynamics (https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/collection-views-and-uidynamics/), but is there any solution that can be used for cross-platform development?
Any help would be appreciated!